# TextBox Border Blue Color When Empty Then border Color Red vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox

TextBox  Border Blue Color When Empty Then border Color Red vb.net i am using the below code but not working

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim p As New Pen(Color.Blue, 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, New Rectangle(TextBox1.Location + New Size(1, 1), TextBox1.Size - New Size(2, 2)))
        p.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then

            TextBox1.Region = New Region(New Rectangle(2, 2, TextBox1.Width - 4, TextBox1.Height - 4))
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You can draw a border using the Container's Paint method. But, what if you change the TextBox parent, maybe adding the TextBox to another container: a GroupBox or a Panel? I suggest to build a CustomControl (a Control derived from TextBox) and override its WndProc, handling the `WM_PAINT` message to draw a custom border, using [ControlPaint.DrawBorder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder). In this case, the Border will always be painted correctly. You can regulate the Border, setting the Control's `BorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` or `Fixed3D`.

Comment: Another option is to build a UserControl, using a TextBox as the edit control and paint a colored Border around it. You have many more design options here, combining a UserControl with a CustomControl derived from TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    With TextBox1
        Dim p As New Pen(If(.Text = "", Color.Red, Color.Blue), 2)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, .Left - 1, .Top - 1, .Width + 2, .Height + 2)
        p.Dispose()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear ok Coding but i want when textbox is empty then border color red

Comment: Dear Sir when i run the form then textbox border color should be blue when textbox is empty that i click the button the textbox border color should be red . i need like this type coding